# Какой глагол в русском языке подходит к междометию «ха»?

Tags: морфология, глаголы

Когда человек охает, можно написать «охнул»:

> — Вот дела, — охнул Андрей Иванович. — Сайт StackExchange не работает.

> — Ох, Артемушка, — охнула Екатерина. — Как же ты теперь без нас
> жить-то будешь?

Но как выразить действие по отношению к междометию «ха»? Первое, что приходит на ум, — это «усмехнулся». Однако, как мне кажется, это не совсем подходящее слово. Есть ли какие-то конкретные варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ха́хать «смеяться, шутить»... (Словарь Макса Фасмера)

https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D1%85/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Спасибо. Какое-то супер-редко применимое слово. Впервые вижу, если честно. Получается, что в диалоге это будет «хохотнул»? Вряд ли есть слово «хахатнул»))

Comment: @Theej Будет так: *хахнул*. Это слово давно устарело, есть только в толковом словаре Даля. Но такие слова как бы можно создать для этой цели: *не хахай/хохай/хухай*. Но констатация факта уже звучит некорректно: *он хахнул/хохнул/хухнул*.

Comment: @oleedd спасибо.